# How to call named field in excel formula through reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to re explain my issue, Column A, B, C, has numbers between 1 to 100 till 500 cells and I named column A as Feb, Column B as Mar & Column C as Apr... Now I Have created one vba dropdown and it has the values February, March, April......  Now I want if i select January then sum of Jan named values sum i should get in result and if i select February then Feb named column values sum i should get... I want formula for this but I dont want to write Named in formula three times for january, February, March, so suggest me the alternative...

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe `And( CountIf( 'Unique User Calculation'!K:K,Calculation!M1 ), D2 > 0 )` ?

Comment: I am re trying to explain my issue again..

Comment: I have edited the question.. could you please check now...

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown is in D1 and Jan, Feb, Mar is in row 1 then use,

```
=sum(index(a:c, 0, match(d1, 1:1, 0)))
```

[image]